# VBA Excel - Importing from Access and Summing Data

Tags: vba, excel, ms-access

I am using a userform in excel to allow users to import claims data from an Access database and paste it into a destination in the workbook.

The code below allows the user to import claim numbers for each of the last 5 years for a particular policy number.

The access database currently summarizes claims data so that all the claims for policy Y in year Y are on one row. However, I need to change the code so that the individual claim amounts can be pulled in and then adjusted based on parameters set out in the userform (i.e. capping claims at 100,000) and then summarized so that all the (adjusted claims) are on a single row for each year.

I have included an image of what the database structure looked like before and what it looks like now. I would like to include something that loops over all the claims in an underwriting year and sums up the total.

[database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YgoZZ.gif)

Without getting into too much detail, I would like know how to summarize the data after I have adjusted them. Do I need another loop in the code below?

```
Public Const RawdataDB = "N:\***\Rawdata DB.accdb"

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
  Dim dbRawData As Database
  Dim rTemp As Recordset
  Dim sSQL As String
  Dim YearTemp As Integer
  Dim i As Integer

  i = 1
  Do Until i = 6
    YearTemp = Year(Range("RenewalDate")) - i
    Set dbRawData = OpenDatabase(RawdataDB, False, False, "MS Access;PWD=*****")
    sSQL = "SELECT Galway_Claims.* FROM Galway_Claims WHERE (Galway_Claims.PolicyNo=" & Range("PolicyNoNew") & " AND Galway_Claims.Year=" & Range("UWYear") - 1 & " AND Galway_Claims.HistoricYear=" & i & ");"
    Set rTemp = dbRawData.OpenRecordset(sSQL)
    Controls("ClaimNos" & i).Value = Format(rTemp!ClaimNosD, "0.0")
    i = i + 1
  Loop
  rTemp.Close
End Sub
```

Comment: To be clear: you have the "Database now" from your picture already in your Access database? Or you want to change your import code so that it takes data from "Database before" out of access and puts it into excel in the structure you depicted as "database now"? Could you create a query in access to change the structure and then import it 1:1 into Excel? And you need to get the sum of ClaimAmts for a particular ClaimRef? In Excel?

Comment: Hi Johanness. Yes, I have "database now" in an access database. The database used to be structured as "database before" where the claims details were summarized by year. So all I needed to do was look up the cell in the access table for the particular year/policy. But now, the claims are not summed over year - I want to sum them by year in my code. You're probably thinking why not just keep the "old database" structure but I need to adjust the claims based on parameters in my userform and then summarize (I'm happy with how I would do the adjustment part).

Comment: It still is unclear to me. Your code doesn't make too much sense. Is this working? You SELECT several datasets and then fill them into a control (what kind of control?). And where do you want to put the Sum?

Comment: Hi Johanness. apologies for not being clearer on this. I am quite new to VBA so excuse the messy code. I am pulling data from a claims database (called Galway_claims). The old database used to summarize the data so if a policy had 3 claims in a year the database would have the summarized claims info for each year. I have had to change this since I want to be able to pull in the data (not summarized) and adjust the individuals claims before summing them over (such as capping the claims at a threshold and inflating them to todays prices etc.)

Comment: As a bit of background, underwriters will use this tool I am designing. On the excel tool, the user will want to import the claims history for a policy *(last 5 years of claims from an Access database).The actual claims experience is adjusted for things like inflation etc, and these assumptions are set in the excel tool. therefore unsummarised claims information needs to be pulled in then adjusted and then summarized and dropped in the excel workbook. Does this clear things up at all? Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Sorry. I see your use case. But you provided code I don't get. Hence: It still is unclear to me. Your code doesn't make too much sense. Is this working? You SELECT several datasets and then fill them into a control (what kind of control?). And where do you want to put the Sum?

Comment: Hi Johanness. I'm sorry if it was unclear. In the meantime I have been able to find a solution myself. The code did work but I think in hindsight I should have provided more info. Should I delete this question?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest here seems to sum everything in access: Make another query:

```
sSQL = "SELECT Sum(Galway_Claims.ClaimAmts) as theSum FROM Galway_Claims WHERE (Galway_Claims.PolicyNo=" & Range("PolicyNoNew") & " AND Galway_Claims.Year=" & Range("UWYear") - 1 & " AND Galway_Claims.HistoricYear=" & i & ");"
```

And then read this in like before:

```
    sSQL = "SELECT Galway_Claims.* FROM Galway_Claims WHERE (Galway_Claims.PolicyNo=" & Range("PolicyNoNew") & " AND Galway_Claims.Year=" & Range("UWYear") - 1 & " AND Galway_Claims.HistoricYear=" & i & ");"
    Set rTemp = dbRawData.OpenRecordset(sSQL)
    Controls("ClaimNos" & i).Value = Format(rTemp!ClaimNosD, "0.0")
    sSQL = "SELECT Sum(Galway_Claims.ClaimAmts) as theSum FROM Galway_Claims WHERE (Galway_Claims.PolicyNo=" & Range("PolicyNoNew") & " AND Galway_Claims.Year=" & Range("UWYear") - 1 & " AND Galway_Claims.HistoricYear=" & i & ");"
    Set rTempSum = dbRawData.OpenRecordset(sSQL)
    Controls("ClaimNos" & i).Value = Format(rTempSum!theSum, "0.0")
    ...
```